# Counting characters in array after map

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mapping

I am currently working with an array that looks like this:

```
{
    "OuterArray": [
        {
            "ArrayNumber": "1",
            "InnerArray": [
                "SOMETHING",
                "what about this"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I would like to have an output of

```
InnerArray: SOMETHING, what about this
```

So far, I have it outputting the correct list where `Component1.jsx` has the content as props as so:

```
<h1>InnerArray: {this.props.content}</h1>
```

And `Component2.jsx` takes the array and maps/reduces it:

```
knownIssuesList() {
    return (
        <div>
            {list.OuterArrays
              .map(a=> (
                  <div key={a.ArrayNumber} >
                      <Component1
                          content={a.InnerArray
                            .map(b=> (<span key={a.ArrayNumber}>{b}</span>))
                            .reduce((prev, curr) => [prev, ', ', curr])}
                      />
                  </div>
              ))}
        </div>
    );
  }
```

However, I would like to add a See More functionality where if the outputted list exceeds a certain number of characters, I have the option of cutting the list off short and adding the See More so users can choose to expand it or not. I first wanted to check if it would correctly output the right number of characters in the final result so I replaced `Component1` with:

```
<h1>InnerArray: {this.props.content.length}</h1>
```

and it seems to be giving me the number of items in the array, not the number of characters. How should I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Component1` do this:

```
<Component1
   content={a.InnerArray.join(",")}
/>
```

That will return you an string containing all the elements in your array separated with a ",". After that you can handle the string as you want in the component. And you can check the length in you Component1 calling content.length. I would suggest if you want to render jsx using the content prop, to create an extra prop for the string. SOmething like this:

```
knownIssuesList() {
 return (
  <div>
   {list.OuterArrays.map(a => {
    const arrayNumberString = a.InnerArray.join(",");
    return (
      <div key={a.ArrayNumber}>
        <Component1
          content={<span>{arrayNumberString}</span>}
          length={arrayNumberString.length}
        />
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>
);
}
```

Comment: When I use join(), it gives me [object Object], [object Object]

Comment: Is the InnerArray an array of strings? because the join should do that. If you're trying to use the join with the generated JSX is is not going to work.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I never needed a mapping statement in the first place. Just a simple a.InnerArray.join would have worked

Comment: Yes that's true, the second map is not needed.